# HP Victus battery removed

Tags: laptop, battery

Can I work with Victus 15 laptops with the battery removed? (Directly plugged in AC power)

I want to deliberately do it because of battery lifespan. I searched YouTube and Google and found nothing.

Comment: You should keep in mind that if you don't use your battery for a long time (that includes not charging up and not draining it, the battery will dry out internally and die just as bad as when you keep charging it to 100%.

Comment: Also bear in mind that many modern laptops, [especially Intel machines](https://www.hardwaretimes.com/intel-10th-gen-cpu-power-consumption-explained-pl1-pl2-and-tau/), have CPUs and GPUs which can self-overclock far beyond their stated TDP for brief periods. They might quickly come back down to their "normal" TDP but turbo boost can allow them to draw nearly twice as much as their stated TDP for a brief period. If the power brick can only handle slightly more than the nominal TDP then it would be expected for the battery to handle the overdraw until it drops below expected.

Comment: As a result you could be risking shutdowns due to insufficient power, or system instability by not using a battery. If you care that much then you should simply be researching the cost of replacement batteries.

Comment: With your current battery (or a new one), make sure your computer supports threshold management (HP App working with BIOS) and run always plugged in at 80%.  This is the generally accepted level for always plugged in.